# Moving the background with a scroll effect

Tags: html, css

I am using a scroll effect on the content with the background were I want the background and content to scroll over the banner img and not the nav.

The snag I have is that the body background is not moving with the content, the problem with creating the background on a separate div is that when the page is not the full screen height it leaves a blank background below the footer.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ThAv5/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="navBar"></div> 
<div id="headerBar"></div>
<div id="mainContent"><h1>This is the main content, the yellow background is not scrolling with the text</h1></div>
```

CSS

```
#navBar{
position:fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
width: 100%;
z-index:1000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
    background:red;
    height:50px;
}

 #headerBar{
top: 0;
height: 250px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin:0px auto;
width:100%;
position: fixed;
z-index:-1000;
    background:blue;
 }

  #mainContent{
overflow: auto;
z-index: 0;
margin-top: 250px;
    width:100%;
     height:900px;
  }

  body{
     background:yellow;
    }
```

Thanks in advance
George

Comment: Couldn't you set a background on both a separate div, and on the body?

Comment: No idea why I didnt think of this before! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something you just need to change the `position to relative` on the `#headerBar`

http://jsfiddle.net/ThAv5/2/

```
#headerBar{
    top: 0;
    height: 250px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-1000;
    background:blue;
}
```